# Dojo Pie Chart : Move Slice with out hovering

Tags: angularjs, dojox.charting

I am trying to integrate Angular with Dojo. I have got to a point where I have created a dojo directive and used to display a pie chart. The pie chart displays browser share percentage for chrome, Safari, FF and IE :) and when user hovers over the slices it animates beautifully by coming out.

There are four check boxes representing each of these Browser. What I want to do is when user checks one of the box for browser, I want to programatically move that slice in dojo pie chart.

I was able to achieve this functionality very easily with HighCharts, as the data model has a property called selected and sliced which I updated in Angular controller which resulted in chart updating it self. I am trying to do a similar stuff in Dojo Pie Chart

**UPDATE**

Is there any API in DOJO charting which will allow me to move a slice of Dojo Pie chart programatically(rather than on Mouse Move)

Comment: I don't really see a question...?

Comment: Instead of moving the slice of dojo pie chart on hover, I want to do it programmatically depending upon the user selection

Comment: That's just stating what you want to do.  That's not a question.  To really get help with this issue, please ask a question and then post some code to explain what you've tried, what you've got so far and what is/isn't working.  Then we can help you along.  But we're not going to write all the code for you...

Comment: A. I do not need you to write my code. That's why I did not post.

B. I only need direction how to do it. If you can help, you are very welcome to answer but from seeing from your tags that you have answered, I do not think you would be more of help, because this more of a dojo charting issue. A guy expert in dojo chart would probably understand the question better.

C. Stop generalizing ("But we're not going to write all the code for you").

D. Thanks anyway.